# adding subchilds in menu

Tags: html, css

I need to create menu with transition effect.here is the link for the menu. http://files.www.gethifi.com/images/nicer-navigation-with-css-transitions/demo.html Its is same as what i expected. But in this menu we have parent elements and child elements. Ineed to add sub child elements also.. What change should we need to make..?help me..

Comment: Please show some of the code here so the question can have value for future viewers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hi heres an answer using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">Widgets</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Im another menu</a></li>           
    <li><a href="#">Im another menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Im another menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Im another menu</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#trans-nav").find("li").each(function(){
    //alert("hover");
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(this).find("ul:first").attr('style','display:block');            
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#trans-nav li ul li ul{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:8em;
  background: #63867f;
  width:8em;
}

#trans-nav li ul li ul li a {
  background: #63867f; 
 padding-right:0;
}
```

See it in action on jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/6Xa8k/